# jQuery Autocomplete select: function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

This seems so simple, yet I cannot seem to get it to work:

```
var options, a;
jQuery(function(){
  options = { 
  serviceUrl:'ajax/parts_by_partno.php', 
  select: function(event, ui) { 
    $("#hiddenId").val(ui.item.id); 
    }
  };
  a = $('#fieldWithData').autocomplete(options);
});
```

Once the item is selected from the auto complete list, I want #hiddenId to change its value to the ID of the item selected:

```
$("#hiddenId").val(ui.item.id);
```

I've even tried to just change #hiddenId to something static like this:

```
$("#hiddenId").val('test');
```

Nothing changed.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you get any javascript errors? have you checked in firebug or the chrome dev tools

Comment: No errors in firebug.  The autocomplete is working properly, but #hiddenId is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

have look on this code..hope it will help u

```
$('#selector').autocomplete({
    source: url,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#txtAllowSearch").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $("#txtAllowSearchID").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
    }
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    alert($("#txtAllowSearchID").val(); // get the id from the hidden input
});
```

Comment: Firebug gives me an error saying $('#fieldWithData').autocomplete is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [full blog entry](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/) on how to use the autocomplete module

Basically, you need to add a callback when the select value is changed, like this:

```
 select: function(e, ui) {  

        //create formatted friend  
        var friend = ui.item.value,  
            span = $("<span>").text(friend),  
            a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({  
                href: "javascript:",  
                title: "Remove " + friend  
            }).text("x").appendTo(span);  

            //add friend to friend div  
            span.insertBefore("#to");  
        },  

        //define select handler  
        change: function() {  

            //prevent 'to' field being updated and correct position  
            $("#to").val("").css("top", 2);  
        }  
    });
```